# javascript for loop not executing function until end of loop, then iterating function n number of times

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I am attempting to load some div's with google map images from a loop that adds one to the value of a document.get.  Problem is the getLocation() call comes at the final iteration of the loop, but then iterates the loops n number of times.

```
for(var i = 1; i < length; i++){
var longitude = 1.8612393999999999;
var latitude = 50.7263312;
document.getElementById("longInput").value = longitude;
document.getElementById("latInput").value = latitude;

var mapholder = "mapholderM"+i;
document.getElementById("mapholderValue").value = mapholder;
theMapholder=document.getElementById(mapholder);

getLocation();
}
```

getLocation() uses longInput and latInput values for lat and lon variables, and theMapholder as a place to put the target div image.  Maps are able to get the co ordinates and as explaned below on the final, or end of the loop also the theMapholder value.

I think this is not an issue with getLocation(), and more how I am attempting to use it.
By adding an alert in the getLocation() call and viewing the elements on screen I know that 
the elements are populated though the loop and change, then get location is called n number of times after this happens.  Then getLocation() only picks up the values that are set as the iterations of giving element values are complete.

Adding an alert at the beginning of the loop makes the loop go round n number of times then execute getLocation() only once.

Just to sum up:
loops and changes element values, one by one.
once this is complete getLocation() is called, with the same number of iterations.
getLocation() can now only access the final setting of the elements so only gives one div a map.

Dean

Update:
Sorry to have given incorrect information: it would appear any method call from my loop results in the same behaviour:

```
function pulse(){
     $('#contentDiv').delay(200).fadeOut('slow').delay(50).fadeIn('slow');    
}
```

Calling this method from my loop:

```
for(var i = 1; i < length; i++) {        
    var longitude = 1.8612393999999999;
    var latitude = 50.7263312;

    alert("end of loop");        
    pulse();
}
```

results in an alert n number of times, then pulse is executed?  Sorry for confusion.

Dean

update:
Google maps script:

```
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }

function showPosition(position)
  {
  alert($("#longInput").val()); */
  lat= $("#latInput").val();
  lon= $("#longInput").val();
  latlon=new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
  mapholder=theMapholder;

  alert("getLocation " + theMapholder);

  var myOptions={
  center:latlon,zoom:14,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl:false,
  navigationControlOptions:{style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(theMapholder,myOptions);
  var marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:latlon,map:map,title:"You are here!"});
  }

  function showError(error)
  {
  switch(error.code) 
    {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      x.innerHTML="User denied the request for Geolocation."
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      x.innerHTML="Location information is unavailable."
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      x.innerHTML="The request to get user location timed out."
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      x.innerHTML="An unknown error occurred."
      break;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Using the alert in showPosition I can see that it is only called after the loop has updated the elements.

Why would the a function behave like this, and only be called after the loop has executed everything else?

Comment: Please indent your code. It is very hard to read.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to see the "getLocation()" function.

Comment: @Pointy will take this advice, thank you, please find a function which illustrates the behaviour.

Comment: Effects like "delay", "fadeOut", etc. are **asynchronous**.  The "pulse" function will return immediately, but the effects will continue over time afterwards.

Comment: There also won't be any visual updates until control is returned to the JS event loop.

Comment: @Pointy, when I add alerts to the loop the pulse function does not start until the final alert has been clicked, why is each pulse not executed before the next alert?

Comment: Because that's just not how those functions work. They start animations that proceed via background timers.

Comment: @MattEsch Does this mean there is no way to make visual changes inside a loop using the getLocation() function?

Comment: You cannot make *gradual* changes (like "fadeIn") that way. You can pass callback functions to those animations, and start subsequent animations from the callbacks.

Comment: @Pointy, I have quickly looked up callbacks and understand how you may want to use one as if your executing something that will want to complete before moving on.  What I cannot understand is why functions are being called after everything else is completed and looped though?

Comment: There are no way to make multiple visual changes inside a for loop where the UI updates after each iteration of that for loop. You have to implement it using async callbacks, like using setTimeout

Comment: The calls to functions like "fadeIn" return immediately even though the effect does not happen immediately. That is simply the way those functions work.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for the helpful advice to understand the pulse function and directing me to callbacks and starting subsequent animations.

Comment: @MattEsch thanks for advice about visual changes, it has influenced my final code and will read up on async callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

As anyone is aware that reads this it was a little confusing, probably due to needing to learn more and javascript although as you will see in the comments there is some good adivice to learn from for me.  Any how my solution to the problem:

getLocation() was being itterated, AFTER the loop had completed iterating over all the other code.  So as a hack, when the getLocation() method is iterated that was the time make the element value changes that the function could use:

```
  var y=1;
  var x=document.getElementById("demo");

  function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }

  function showPosition(position)
  {
    var longitude = -1.8612393999999999;
    var latitude = 50.7263312;

    document.getElementById("longInput").value = longitude;
    document.getElementById("latInput").value = latitude;

    var mapholder = "mapholderM"+y;
    document.getElementById("mapholderValue").value = mapholder;
    theMapholder=document.getElementById(mapholder);

    lat= $("#latInput").val();   
    lon= $("#longInput").val();
    latlon=new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
    mapholder=theMapholder; 
    alert("getLocation " + theMapholder+y);
    y++;

    var myOptions={
      center:latlon,zoom:14,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl:false,
      navigationControlOptions:{style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}
    };

  var map=new google.maps.Map(theMapholder,myOptions);
  var marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:latlon,map:map,title:"You are here!"});
}
```

Notice the introduction of variable y which increments in value each time the method is called to use in the get element id.